# Unable to open file using CreateFile function

Tags: c++, file, winapi

Ok so I've been following this tutorial: http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4422&lngWId=3

And so far I've gotten everything to work, up until I need the program to load in a .raw audio file.

Here's the relevant code:

```
LPSTR loadAudioBlock(const char* filename, DWORD* blockSize)
{
HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
DWORD size = 0;
DWORD readBytes = 0;
void* block = NULL;

//open the file

if((hFile = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return NULL;

// get it's size, allocate memory, and then read it into memory

size = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
block = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, size);
ReadFile(hFile, block, size, &readBytes, NULL);

CloseHandle(hFile);
*blockSize = size;
return (LPSTR)block;
}
```

And then my main function which calls it:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
HWAVEOUT hWaveOut; //device handle
WAVEFORMATEX wfx; //struct for format info
MMRESULT result; // for waveOut return values
LPSTR block;
DWORD blockSize;

// first let's set up the wfx format struct

wfx.nSamplesPerSec = 44100; // rate of the sample
wfx.wBitsPerSample = 16; //sample size
wfx.nChannels = 2; // 2 channels = stereo
wfx.cbSize = 0; // no extra info
wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM; //PCM format
wfx.nBlockAlign = (wfx.wBitsPerSample >> 3) * wfx.nChannels;
wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = wfx.nBlockAlign * wfx.nSamplesPerSec;

// then let's open the device

if(waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, 0, 0, CALLBACK_NULL) != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to open Wave Mapper device.\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    ExitProcess(1);
}

// if no errors then close it
printf("The Wave Mapper device was opened successfully!\n");

//load and play file
if((block = loadAudioBlock("ding.raw", &blockSize)) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to load file\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    ExitProcess(1);
}
writeAudioBlock(hWaveOut, block, blockSize);
Sleep(1000);
waveOutClose(hWaveOut);
return 0;
}
```

Everytime I run the program I get the: "Unable to load file" output. I've got the "ding.raw" file in the same directory as my exe. I've also tried doing the full path as "C://path" and "C:/path" but then the compiler just gives me more errors about being unable to load a pdb file.

Any ideas? I'm using the Visual Studio 2012 Professional IDE and compiler.

Comment: When the `CreateFile` call fails, use [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see what error you have. A list of error codes can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The "Windows" OS uses backslashes for paths. So full path should be `C:\\path\\ding.raw`.

Comment: My suspicion is that you are mixing normal character strings in the filename with wide character strings (`const char *` is a normal character string, while `LPCWSTR` is a wide-character string).

Comment: The CreateFile() function complains if I don't use a LPCWSTR. What's the best of remedying this?

Comment: @fasked - Windows is doing forward slashes as well. `"C:/path/ding.raw"` works perfectly well as a file name.

Comment: @Tyler - The cast just tells the compiler not to complain, it doesn't modify the parameter. Try changing the parameter to `const wchar_t*` and pass it a wide string, `L"C:/path/ding.raw"`.

Comment: Instead of using the standard `char` you should be using e.g. `TCHAR` and `LPCTSTR` everywhere. This will make all string and string pointers you pass around be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the standard `char` you should be using e.g. `_TCHAR` and `LPCTSTR` everywhere. This will make all string and string pointers you pass around be correct.

Look at the `argv` argument to `_tmain` and you will see that it uses `_TCHAR` instead of `char`. This is because Windows support both normal characters and Unicode characters depending on a couple of macros. See e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for some more information.

So to solve what is likely your problem (since you don't get the actual error code, see my comment about `GetLastError`) you should change the function like this:

```
void *loadAudioBlock(LPCTSTR filename, DWORD* blockSize)
{
    // ...

    if((hFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return NULL;

    // ...
}
```

And call it like this:

```
// ...

void *block;

if((block = loadAudioBlock(_T("C:\\path\\ding.raw"), &blockSize)) == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to open Wave Mapper device, error code %ld.\n", GetLastError());
    Sleep(1000);
    ExitProcess(1);
}

// ...
```

As you can see I also changed the return type, as the file is binary and won't have any readable text.

Comment: The file still isn't opening. And I'm just getting this error code:

    ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

        2 (0x2)

        The system cannot find the file specified.

So that doesn't help much.

Comment: @TylerJarjoura Even if you provide a full path to the file? With the correct slashes of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
LPSTR loadAudioBlock(const char* filename, DWORD* blockSize)
{
     if((hFile = CreateFile(CA2T(filename), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
return NULL;
}
```

See ATL conversion macros: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx Just casting const char* LPCWSTR doesn't work.

Comment: The compiler says "CA2W" is an undeclared identifier.